# R saving recursive variable

Tags: r, recursion

First of all, i could not find a answer that fits with this.

I am doing this function

```
find.childrens <- function(categoria){
  x <- fromJSON(paste("https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/",categoria,sep=""))
  if(!is.null(nrow(x$children_categories))){
    for(i in 1:nrow(x$children_categories)){
    find.childrens(x$children_categories[i,1])}
  }else{print(x$id)}
}

saving <- find.childrens(categoria="MLA122518")
```

That works, but i cant save the return ( the return goes where  the print is)

Anyone knows how to help me?
Regards!

Comment: you need to `return` a value

Comment: I did, but it doesnt work. else{return(x$id)} Instead of else{print(x$id)}

Comment: In the top half, there is no return, and you're calling the recursive re-entry in a loop. You need to gather these results, then return everything, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive function should always return something and maybe concatenate the ids if you want all categories under a category :

```
find.childrens <- function(categoria){
  x <- fromJSON(paste("https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/",categoria,sep=""))
  ids <- NULL
  if(!is.null(nrow(x$children_categories))){
    for(i in 1:nrow(x$children_categories)){
      ids <- c(ids, find.childrens(x$children_categories[i,1]))
    }
  }else{
    ids <- x$id
  }
  return(ids)
}

saving <- find.childrens(categoria="MLA122518")

> saving
[1] "MLA385241" "MLA385242"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to both store and return the value returned by each recursive jump through the function:

```
library("jsonlite")
find.childrens <- function(categoria) {
  x <- fromJSON(paste("https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/", categoria, sep=""))
  count <- 0L
  if (length(x[["children_categories"]])) {
    for(i in seq_along(x[["children_categories"]][["id"]])) {
      count <- count + find.childrens(x[["children_categories"]][i,"id"])
    }
  } else {
      count <- x[["total_items_in_this_category"]]
  }
  count
}

(saving <- find.childrens(categoria="MLA122518"))
## [1] 113
```